# Need to do 64 bit multiplication on a machine with 32 bit longs

Tags: 64-bit, integer, 32-bit, multiplication

I'm working on a small embedded system that has 32 bit long ints.  For one calculation I need output the time since 1970 in ms.  I can get the time in 32 bit unsigned long seconds since 1970, but how can I represent this as a 64 bit no. of ms if my biggest int is only 32bits?  I'm sure stackoverflow will have a cunning answer!  I am using Dynamic C, close to standard C.  I have some sample code from another system which has a 64 bit long long data type:

```
long long T = (long long)(SampleTime * 1000.0 + 0.5);
data.TimeLower = (unsigned int)(T & 0xffffffff);
data.TimeUpper = (unsigned short)((T >> 32) & 0xffff);
```

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: It's Dynamic C, an quirky superset of C for embedded systems

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only multiplying by 1000 (seconds -> millis), you can do it with two 16 bit mutliplies and one add and a bit of bit fiddling, I have used your putative data type to store the result below:

```
uint32_t time32 = time();
uint32_t t1 = (time32 & 0xffff) * 1000;
uint32_t t2 = ((time32 >> 16) * 1000) + (t1 >> 16);
data.TimeLower = (uint32_t) ((t2 & 0xffff) << 16) | (t1 & 0xffff);
data.TimeUpper = (uint32_t) (t2 >> 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach, assuming you have a 16x16->32 multiply available, would be to split both numbers into 16-bit high and low parts, compute four partial products, and add the results.  If you don't have a 16x16->32 primitive which is faster than a 32x32->32 primitive, though, I'm not sure what the best approach would be.  I would think that a 32x32->32 multiply should be more useful than a 16x16->32, but I can't think how one would use it.

Personally, I wish there were a standard primitive to return the top half of a NxN multiply (32x32, certainly; also 16x16 for smaller machines and 64x64 for larger ones).

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful if you were more specific about what kinds of calculations you need to do. 64-bit multiplication implemented with 32-bit operations is quite slow, and you may have the additional overhead of 64-bit division (to convert back to seconds and milliseconds), which is even slower.

Without knowing more about what exactly you need to do, it seems to me that it would be more efficient to use a struct, containing a 32-bit unsigned int for the number of seconds and a 16-bit int for the number of milliseconds (the "remainder"). (Or use a 32-bit int for the milliseconds if 64-bit alignment is more important than saving a couple of bytes.)

Comment: I added some sample code from another system which has a 64bit long long type